# Problems aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2 crosscompiling for armv7l

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core

I downloaded the `aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2` repository and I compiled for x86_64 with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

WORKSPACE=/home/jose/repos/sdk-cpp-workspace
BUILD_TYPE="Debug"


cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$WORKSPACE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DBUILD_DEPS=ON ../aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2
cmake --build . --target install --config $BUILD_TYPE
```

Now I'm trying to crosscompile it for an armv7l architecture using this script (an using an already created toolchain):

```
#!/bin/sh

WORKSPACE=/home/jose/repos/sdk-cpp-workspace
BUILD_TYPE="Debug"

. /opt/poky/2.2.2/environment-setup-cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$WORKSPACE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DUSE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=TRUE ../aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2 
cmake --build . --target install
```

And I get this ouptput:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/poky/2.2.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/poky/2.2.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/poky/2.2.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/poky/2.2.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- AWS CRT C++ v0.14.1
-- CMake 3.16.3
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_GCC_OVERFLOW_MATH_EXTENSIONS
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_GCC_OVERFLOW_MATH_EXTENSIONS - Failed
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_MSVC_MULX
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_MSVC_MULX - Failed
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_WINAPI_DESKTOP
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_WINAPI_DESKTOP - Failed
-- Performing Test AWS_ARCH_INTEL
-- Performing Test AWS_ARCH_INTEL - Failed
-- Performing Test AWS_ARCH_ARM64
-- Performing Test AWS_ARCH_ARM64 - Failed
-- Performing Test AWS_ARCH_ARM32
-- Performing Test AWS_ARCH_ARM32 - Success
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_GCC_INLINE_ASM
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_GCC_INLINE_ASM - Success
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_AUXV
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_AUXV - Success
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_EXECINFO
-- Performing Test AWS_HAVE_EXECINFO - Success
-- Performing Test AWS_SHOULD_DISABLE_STRINGOP_OVERFLOW
-- Performing Test AWS_SHOULD_DISABLE_STRINGOP_OVERFLOW - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_M_AVX2_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAVE_M_AVX2_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_AVX2_INTRINSICS
-- Performing Test HAVE_AVX2_INTRINSICS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_MM256_EXTRACT_EPI64
-- Performing Test HAVE_MM256_EXTRACT_EPI64 - Failed
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Performing Test HAS_MOUTLINE_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test HAS_MOUTLINE_ATOMICS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_64BIT_FILE_OFFSET_BY_DEFAULT
-- Performing Test HAS_64BIT_FILE_OFFSET_BY_DEFAULT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_64BIT_FILE_OFFSET_VIA_DEFINES
-- Performing Test HAS_64BIT_FILE_OFFSET_VIA_DEFINES - Success
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stdbool.h
-- Looking for stdbool.h - found
-- Performing Test HAS_WGNU
-- Performing Test HAS_WGNU - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSCONF
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSCONF - Success
-- Looking for pthread_attr_setaffinity_np
-- Looking for pthread_attr_setaffinity_np - found
-- Performing Test HAS_SANITIZERS
-- Performing Test HAS_SANITIZERS - Failed
-- Packaging currently only supported on Fedora.
-- Checking for module 'libunwind-generic'
--   No package 'libunwind-generic' found
libunwind not found. Disabling unwind tests.
-- Go not found. Disabling some code generation and using pre-generated code in generated-src/
-- Perl not found. Disabling some code generation and using pre-generated code in generated-src/
-- Test stdalign_check.c passed, enabling AWS_LC_STDALIGN_AVAILABLE
-- Test builtin_swap_check.c passed, enabling AWS_LC_BUILTIN_SWAP_SUPPORTED
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /opt/poky/2.2.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
Copying platform assembly files from /home/jose/repos/sdk-cpp-workspace/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/generated-src/linux-x86/crypto/ to /home/jose/repos/sdk-cpp-workspace/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2-cross-build/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto
-- S2N found target: crypto
-- Using libcrypto from AWS-LC
-- Performing Test AWS_ARM32_CRC
-- Performing Test AWS_ARM32_CRC - Failed
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    DISCARD_USER_INCLUDE
    USE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE


-- Build files have been written to: /home/jose/repos/sdk-cpp-workspace/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2-cross-build
Scanning dependencies of target aws-c-common
[  0%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/allocator.c.o
[  0%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/allocator_sba.c.o
[  0%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/arch/arm/asm/cpuid.c.o
[  0%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/array_list.c.o
[  0%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/assert.c.o
[  1%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/byte_buf.c.o
[  1%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/cache.c.o
[  1%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/codegen.c.o
[  1%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/command_line_parser.c.o
[  1%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/common.c.o
[  1%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/condition_variable.c.o
[  1%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/date_time.c.o
[  1%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/device_random.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/encoding.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/error.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/fifo_cache.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/hash_table.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/lifo_cache.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/linked_hash_table.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/log_channel.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/log_formatter.c.o
[  2%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/log_writer.c.o
[  3%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/logging.c.o
[  3%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/lru_cache.c.o
[  3%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/math.c.o
[  3%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/memtrace.c.o
[  3%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/clock.c.o
[  3%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/condition_variable.c.o
[  3%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/device_random.c.o
[  3%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/environment.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/file.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/mutex.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/process.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/rw_lock.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/system_info.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/thread.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/posix/time.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/priority_queue.c.o
[  4%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/process_common.c.o
[  5%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/promise.c.o
[  5%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/ref_count.c.o
[  5%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/resource_name.c.o
[  5%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/ring_buffer.c.o
[  5%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/statistics.c.o
[  5%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/string.c.o
[  5%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/task_scheduler.c.o
[  5%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/thread_scheduler.c.o
[  6%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/thread_shared.c.o
[  6%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/uuid.c.o
[  6%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-common/CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/xml_parser.c.o
[  6%] Linking C static library libaws-c-common.a
[  6%] Built target aws-c-common
Scanning dependencies of target aws-c-compression
[  6%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-compression/CMakeFiles/aws-c-compression.dir/source/compression.c.o
[  6%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-compression/CMakeFiles/aws-c-compression.dir/source/huffman.c.o
[  6%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-compression/CMakeFiles/aws-c-compression.dir/source/huffman_testing.c.o
[  6%] Linking C static library libaws-c-compression.a
[  6%] Built target aws-c-compression
Scanning dependencies of target global_target
[  6%] Built target global_target
Scanning dependencies of target fipsmodule
[  6%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeFiles/fipsmodule.dir/bcm.c.o
[  6%] Building C object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeFiles/fipsmodule.dir/fips_shared_support.c.o
[  6%] Building ASM object crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeFiles/fipsmodule.dir/aesni-x86.S.o
/home/jose/repos/sdk-cpp-workspace/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2-cross-build/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto/fipsmodule/aesni-x86.S: Assembler messages:
/home/jose/repos/sdk-cpp-workspace/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2-cross-build/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto/fipsmodule/aesni-x86.S:2513: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
make[2]: *** [crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeFiles/fipsmodule.dir/build.make:89: crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeFiles/fipsmodule.dir/aesni-x86.S.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1621: crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-lc/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeFiles/fipsmodule.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Comment: The issue is that you're pulling in an x86 assembly file (`aesni-x86.S`) in a build for the ARM architecture. Could be the aws-crt-cpp cmake files not correctly propagating the cross-toolchain to the dependencies. I've previously built the same library for ARMv8 - I specify `-DBUILD_DEPS=OFF`, and then just provide my own libcrypto - which works fine...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still facing this issue. Providing my solution for others facing this isuue. For me adding this flag fixed the issue.

```
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm
```

With this flag the AWS sdk was able to pick up correct assembly files for arm.

Link to AWS IOT Git : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lc/issues/384